# Class contiguous data

Tags: c++, class

I have a C++ class which has four private floats and a bunch of nonstatic public functions that operate on this data.

Is it guaranteed, or possible to make it so, that the four floats are contiguous and there is no padding. This would make the class the size of four floats, and it's address would be that of the first float.

Comment: I don't know of guarantees, but in most systems, I don't see any reason why they should not be contiguous.  However, in most cases, one shouldn't care how class members are mapped.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That depends on your compiler.

You can use `#pragma pack(1)` with e.g. [MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html), or `#pragma pack 1` with [aCC](http://docs.hp.com/en/8/pragmas.htm#pragma-pack).

For example, assuming `MSVC`/`gcc`:

```
#pragma pack(1)
class FourFloats
{
    float f1, f2, f3, f4;
};
```

Or better:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
class FourFloats
{
    float f1, f2, f3, f4;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

That basically disables padding and guarantees that the `floats` are contiguous. However, to ensure that the size of your class is actually `4 * sizeof(float)`, it must not have a [vtbl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), which means [virtual members](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr029.htm) are off-limits.

Comment: Do I Specify the packing during the class definition?

Comment: And this fulfills all the requirements? If so, fantastic, this will drastically improve efficiency.

Comment: @Alexander, if none of your public nonstatic functions are `virtual`, that should do it.

Comment: This is so dangerous! The compiler is free to put these elements _anywhere it likes_. The only safe way is to put them in an array.

Comment: While a packed class will work (a packed struct that's a member of the class would be marginally better imo) I like the array solution better as well. It's just more sensible.

Comment: @TonyK: Not everywhere, `f2` has to come _somewhere_ after `f1`, so at an offset `>=sizeof(float)`. With an array, the offset must be `==sizeof(float)`.

Answer (score 10):

The C++ standard guarantees that *arrays* are stored contiguously with no intermediate padding.  If you want to make sure the floats are contiguous, and you don't want to rely on compiler-specific padding directives, you can simply store your floats in an array:

```
private:
float array_[4];
```

However, this won't guarantee necessarily that the class will be the size of four floats. But you can ensure that any operation which specifically addresses the internal array of floats will be operating on a contiguous array.

But more generally, maybe you should question why you need this guarantee.  Usually, the only reason you'd care about the memory layout of the class is if you're going to treat it as a serialized byte array.  In that case, it's usually better to create a dedicated serialization/deserialization function, rather than relying on any particular memory layout.

Comment: Actually, because of C compatibility requirements, the array address _must_ be the same as the class address (if it's the first member, which is obviously the case if it's the only member).

Comment: @MSalters even in the presence of vtbls?

Comment: @nik: no, those classes cant be C compatible anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `#pragma pack` described [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28VS.80%29.aspx) for this.