# Could Qt Synchronisation classes be used with MSVC compiler

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, qt, visual-c++

In the Qt Synchronizing threads documentation listed here:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-synchronizing.html

They wrote:

> Note: Qt's synchronization classes rely on the use of properly aligned pointers. For instance, you cannot use packed classes with MSVC.

The sentence is not clear.

Which are the limitations of using Qt Synchronization classes with MSVC  compiler?

Comment: If you don't use "packed classes" you should be OK to use them. Packed classes is where you manipulate the struct alignment. If you don't change anything here you are probably just fine.

Comment: @Hayt: thanks, +1. You can write a complete answer. I will upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Alignment* refers to a restriction on the addresses of objects of certain types. For the compilers supported by Qt, there's just one sort of alignment restriction: some addresses *should* be a multiple of 2,4 or 8.

There are a few ways in which this restriction can be violated. In a packed class, when you have a `float` followed by a `char` followed by another `float` there will be no gaps between the three members (that's why they're called packed). As a result, the second `float` has an address that's 5 higher than the first. It's fairly obvious that one of the two addresses is not a multiple of 4 (the alignment of `float`).

Another way in which this can occur is casting a random `char*` to `float*`. The last two bits of the `char*` *should* be zero in this case.

MSVC++ can deal with such *unaligned* data (it's just slightly slower), but it does so by having the CPU load the data in two operations. This breaks Qt's synchronization which assumes that data is loaded in one operation, such that you get either an old or a new value. If the load is split in two operations, the first may see an old value and the second a new value. The result is that the register contains a mix of old and new bits (!)

Comment: More complete answer, +1.I should tick this as the answer.

Comment: @ProEns08 You don't really need to comment on your upvotes etc.

Answer (score 3):

You're facing a documentation bug, with following fix:

> Note: Qt's synchronization classes rely on the use of properly aligned pointers. For instance, you cannot use t̲h̲e̲m̲ i̲n̲ packed classes <strike>with MSVC</strike>.

MSVC is a red herring. Qt's synchronization classes don't work with packed structures period, on all platforms Qt is supported on - since all these platforms support packed structures, and know how to access unaligned members of such structures.

Comment: could you explain more the cause for this. Why did you affirm that. Especially that the documentation is edited and revised by Qt developers themselves.

Comment: The cause is very, very simple: nobody bothered to submit a fix to the documentation. Qt developers aren't some divine entity with unlimited time and resources. No documentation is perfect.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. To tick it as the answer, Your answer should be affirmed by Qt itself.

Comment: Why did you say that MSVC is a red herring. I did not understand this expression.

Comment: red herring means "something, especially a clue, that is or is intended to be misleading or distracting"

Comment: "Your answer should be affirmed by Qt itself." Haha. You can test it yourself. It's not hard. You don't have to trust me, or Qt developers either!

Comment: Did you mean that Qt documentation editor put this false information premeditated?

Comment: Not at all. I mean that appeal to authority is unnecessary. If you're seeking truth, you don't need to trust neither documentation nor me. Trust experimental results and machine code.

Answer (score 2):

It should not be an issue if you don't use packed classes (if you don't know what that is you are likely not to be using them).

See here for some information about what they are: [Class contiguous data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177346/class-contiguous-data)

Comment: Actually, packed classes are just one of the examples that could cause a failure. Therefore, avoiding packed classes is necessary but not sufficient.