# base class is a reference to another object

Tags: c++

I just encountered a snippet of code which seems quite strange to me(see below as a minimal example), the `derived::base` is a reference to another object of type of `base`, can someone help me to answer the questions in the comments?

```
class base{
public:
   int a;
   int b;
};

class derived : public base{
public:
   double c;
   void run(const base & bs){
     ((base &) *this) = bs; // what does this line do? 
                            // Is derived::base now a copy of bs? 
                            // If yes, but why not write ((base) *this) = bs?
                            // if not, then derived::base is a reference to bs, 
                            // then does it mean the memory of derived::base
                            // and members of derived are no longer contiguous?
     std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;

   }
};
```

**PS**

comments by @LightnessRacesinOrbit helped a lot to clear the questions, but I can only accept an answer post, the best is by @WhiZTiM

Comment: All it does is invoke the copy constructor of the base class which will copy the the members of the base class (i.e. `a` and `b`) without touching anything in the derived part of the object (i.e. `c`). I don't see why the memory wouldnt be contiguous anymore.

Comment: afaik you never had the guarantee that the objects members are stored in contiguous memory, even without this "copy only the base class members" trick. Maybe there is some misunderstanding on the meaning of "contiguous". Can you explain a bit more what exactly worries you about that code?

Comment: @imreal, but why not write `((base) *this) = bs` if invoking the copy constructor?

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177346/class-contiguous-data), [also related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430848/are-class-members-garaunteed-to-be-contiguous-in-memory)

Comment: @tobi303, my worry is that if it is just invoking the copy constructor, why not just write `((base) *this) = bs` or `derived::base = bs`?

Comment: not sure, but I think `((base) *this) = bs;` would be just fine as well. Did you try it? Is this a typo: `base = bs` ? `base` is a type in the example, not an object

Comment: also `derived::base = bs` would not compile

Comment: @tobi303, `((base) *this) = bs` gives different behavior, and any reason why `derived::base = bs` doesn't compile?

Comment: @imreal: _"All it does is invoke the copy constructor of the base class"_ No, it doesn't.

Comment: Clever solution to copying an object … For exactly that reason seeing this in a code review would immediately worry me. It reeks of being too clever and may very well be a symptom of a deeper design problem. I’d insist on a rock solid (and documented!) reason why such acrobatics are unavoidable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void run(const base & bs){
     ((base &) *this) = bs; 
     std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
}
```

The above code can be broken down as:

```
void run(const base & bs){
     base& base_of_this_instance = *this; 
     base_of_this_instance = bs;
     std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
}
```

The memory for an object of `derived` may be laid out as:

```
||  int a  |x|  int b  |y|  int c  ||   // <- x and y represents some hypothetical padding
||        base         |y|         ||   // <- We can slice `derived` and retrieve only base
||           derived               ||   // <- Memory consumed by derived
```

In your `derived::run` method, first, a reference to the `base` portion of `derived` is obtained, secondly that `base` is assigned to `bs`. This assignment will invoke the copy assignment operator of `base`. That means the base portion will now now hold a copy of whatever was in `bs`.

Comment: What differences does if make if it is written as `((base) *this) = bs`?

Comment: @Allanqunzi: You get a useless temporary copy instead.

Comment: `((base) *this) = bs` will simply have `bs` assigned to a sliced portion `base` of derived. Since that *sliced* portion is a temporary unnamed object, it will be destructed at the end of the `;`. In effect you get wasted work. `derived` will not be affected

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, why it is temporary? I thought `*this` would be a reference to the current class.

Comment: @Allanqunzi: Because that's what casting does. `(base)` is a cast.

Comment: @Allanqunzi And actually `*this` is _not_ a reference, though it does refer to the original object in much the way a reference would.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, thanks I think now I get most of it except the part "*this is not a reference"

Comment: @Allanqunzi, well, [`this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) itself is a `prvalue` expression, [dereferencing it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_indirection_operator), produce the `lvalue` of the original object. This is akin to using `d` after creating `d` like `derived d;`

Comment: @Allanqunzi: Dereferencing a pointer gives you an lvalue `T`, not an lvalue `T&`. It's a technical detail that you don't need to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

The result of

```
((base &) *this)
```

is references to base class

You can save it to a variable:

```
base& refToBase = ((base &) *this);
```

refToBase is a reference to the same object which is this

After that you have assignment

```
refToBase = bs;
```

It will assign bs's value to refToBase object

Like this:

```
int i = 10;
int p = 20;
int& refI = i;
int& refP = p;
refI = refP; // i == 20
p = 15; // p ==15 but i == 20
```

So after "strange code" from your example are executed we have  the copies of bs.a and bs.b in derived::a and derived::b

the memory of derived::base and derived::c is still one batch

Comment: why not just write `((base) *this) = bs` or `derived::base = bs`?

Comment: @Allanqunzi: Because the first creates a temporary copy, and the second is a fantasy