# How to make contiguous data in class C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, memory-alignment

I am using Visual C++ on Windows 10.
I want to make class `Vector4` such that it has members `x, y, z, t` and they stored contiguously to provide `operator[]` and other functions:

```
class Vector4
{
public:
    float operator[](size_t idx)
    {
       return &x + idx;
    }
public:
   float x, y, z, t;
}
```

But I found out that such implementation works not on every compiler(On Visual C++ it works well).
And I dont know how to fix it, maybe write something like this: `class alignas(sizeof(float)) Vector4;`

Comment: This cannot be done in a standard-compliant manner. You either have to concede the `.x` and `.y` access in favor of `.x()` and `.y()` or you have to use a `union` extension that allows you to access inactive members. As far as I am aware, all of the big 3 compilers guarantee it to be safe.

Comment: Use an array and have reference members x, y, z, t refering to elements in that array

Comment: You mean like `union {float xs[4]; struct {float x, y, z, w;};};`?

Comment: @André ... and have your objects take 3x more space. You should also a least explain how to write an assignment operator.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Indeed, but that is not one of the constraints in the question. And, as Fureeish nicely mentioned, there is not really a standard compliant alternative.

Comment: @André "There is not really a standard compliant alternative" is the right answer. "Add reference members" is not one. It is not something a real world programmer would do in a real world program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From: [C++ - Class contiguous data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177346/class-contiguous-data)**

> You can use #pragma pack(1) with e.g. MSVC and gcc, or #pragma pack 1 with aCC.

As said in the answer `#pragma pack(1)` will disables padding and guarantees that the members are contiguous:

> That basically disables padding and guarantees that the floats are contiguous. However, to ensure that the size of your class is actually 4 * sizeof(float), it must not have a vtbl, which means virtual members are off-limits.

See also the official C++ documentation: **[Implementation defined behavior control](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/impl)**

The answer gives two ways:

```cpp
#pragma pack(1)
class FourFloats
{
    float f1, f2, f3, f4;
};
```

and

```cpp
#pragma pack(push, 1)
class FourFloats
{
    float f1, f2, f3, f4;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same need, and I did something like this:

```
class Vector4
{

public:
    // This is our data (4 doubles)
    union {
        double data[4];    // access as an array
        struct {
            double x;       // access as individual values
            double y;
            double z;
            double t;
        };
    };

public:
    // default construct
    Vector4() : data{ 0, 0, 0, 1 }{}
    // construct from 4 doubles
    Vector4(const double& x, const double &y, const double& z, const double & t) :
        x(x), y(y), z(z), t(t){}

    // const and non-const [] operators
    double& operator[](const size_t Index){ return data[Index]; }
    double operator[](const size_t Index) const { return data[Index]; }
};
```

This will allow accessing by [] or by .x, .y, etc.

```
Vector4 my_vec(1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 1.0);
auto x = my_vec.x;
auto y = my_vec[1];
```

I also implemented many other useful functions, such as dot product, cross product, etc.

Comment: Thank you, it must work, but I find other solution to this question easier